# Add CData to improperly formed XML element

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to convert xml to have CDATA around text (in java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800786/best-way-to-convert-xml-to-have-cdata-around-text-in-java)

Hello I have the following code which is parsing some XML by element name.

```
NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
```

The "title" of each node is improperly formed XML, it is not wrapped in CDATA, which leads to all sorts of errors when there are special characters. I am unable to manipulate the XML from the source. How would I go about fixing the element before I begin to use it?

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of how it is malformed: if it's not well-formed, for example, parsing will fail (and you must modify 'raw' textual xml); but there are many other kinds of problems one might have ("double escaping" etc)

Answer (score 1):

Ask the provider of that XML document to fix it, if it's not proper XML.